How to sharing code across internal Package.swift files
I have a project with a lot of internal Swift Packages. In each Package.swift file, I define certain things like Swift Settings I want to use for that package, as well as helper functions for generating products, unit test targets etc. For example, in each package file I have:
extension [SwiftSetting] {

    /// A default set of Swift settings to enable for modules.
    static let `default`: [SwiftSetting] = [
        .existentialAny,
        .internalImportsByDefault
    ]
}

However, it is very cumbersome to rewrite this in every single package file. I was wondering if there is a way to share code across all internal package files to simplify and streamline this process. Not sure if this is possible, but in Package.swift files we can import PackageDescription which provides all of the basic package-defining types - is there a way we can import sets of custom code just like PackageDescription?

Not possible at the moment.

I have a project that had a lot of internal packages but I got tired of having build issues with Xcode from time to time and that I like you needed to duplicate settings between packages so I changed to one package with multiple targets instead and this works really well for me. I still have a clear separation between modules and I can apply settings once for all my targets and Xcode is giving me less issues with this a solution.

The package.swift files are made to be standalone files without dependencies, So this is not possible unfortunately.
But if your shared code is mostly data, You can put it in a structured Json file and read it in the package file

The shared code would be utility rather than data, much like PackageDescription provides. Since PackageDescription is able to be imported in package files, I hope in the future apple allows for custom frameworks to be used in package files as well.
